dq axes orientation in power system dynamics
I am reading a book on Power System Dynamics (Machowski: Power System Dynamics). In the book, before the analyses are carried out, there are two assumptions being made on the dq axes:

The rotor of the electrical machine (the analysis is primarily for synchronous machines in generator mode) rotates in the counter clockwise direction.
The q-axis lags the d-axis by 90\$ ^{\circ} \$.

The second assumption here confuses me as in a previous electrical machines course that I had, the q-axis led the d-axis. Is there any specific reason from a dynamics standpoint that this assumption makes sense? In both cases, the rotor rotates in the counter clockwise direction so I don't understand why it should be different.
